# Why does feeding a nullptr to std::ostream produce a signal 11, aka segmentation fault, from the OS, and how do I handle it?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, c++11, iostream, nullptr

I have a `Date` class with a `Date::print` method, that I'm attempting to test. The method itself is defined as

```
void Date::print(std::ostream *printStream) const
{
  invariant();
   *printStream << day_ << '.' << month_ << '.' << year_;
}
```

and the test function as

```
void Unittest::print()
{
    // Creating and printing the date into string, checking if ok
    Date d(4, 5, 2000);
    std::ostringstream printStream;
    d.print(&printStream);
    QCOMPARE(printStream.str(), std::string("4.5.2000"));

    // Testing with a nullptr
    d.print(nullptr);
}
```

The valid date passes the test, no problem, but testing for a `nullptr` produces a segmentation fault. How should I modify the method definition to handle the `nullptr` case?

Comment: You are dereferencing a `nullptr` with `*printStream << ...`. That is undefined behavior. Note that you are not _feeding_ a `nullptr` _to_ `std::ostream` but trying to _use_ `nullptr` _as_ a `std::ostream`. What is the behavior you expect?

Comment: @Max Langhof Ah, true that. Maybe the sensible thing to do is to not perform that particular test at all?

Comment: Another sensible thing would be to take the `printStream` by reference. I don't think the function can do anything meaningful when given a `nullptr`, so why allow it semantically?

Comment: So define `Date::print` as `void Date::print(std::ostream &printStream) const;` instead of `void Date::print(std::ostream *printStream) const;`?

Comment: Yes, that looks good.

Comment: I don't get the question.  What else do you think dereferencing a null pointer means?